# How to properly use @pytest.mark.foo("bar")

Tags: python, pytest, pytest-markers

I have three Python files:

**file_1.py**

```
@pytest.mark.foo("bar1")
def method_1():
   - code -
```

**file_2.py**

```
@pytest.mark.foo("bar2")
def method_2():
   - code -
```

**file_3.py**

```
@pytest.mark.foo("bar1")
def method_3():
   - code -
```

How can I run only the files/methods with *@pytest.mark.foo("bar1")*? I tried to use *-m* argument, but didn't worked. -k is not recommended since I have a hundred of files mixed with these marks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pytest run only tests with specific marker attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67200501/pytest-run-only-tests-with-specific-marker-attribute)

Comment: I assume that your methods are test methods, e.g. `test_mothod_1` etc, otherwise I may have not understood the question.